# How do I find the eigenvalue(s) of this $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following matrix

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1^2 & c_1 c_2 & c_1 c_3 \\
c_2 c_1 & c_2^2 & c_2 c_3 \\
c_3 c_1 & c_3 c_2 & c_3^2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Rows 2 and 3 are linear combinations of row 1, so the matrix has rank 1. Given this information, is it obvious to find the non-zero eigenvalue of this matrix?

The eigenvalue is $c_1^2$, but I cannot see by which theorem that holds.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Call the matrix $C$. You know already that the characteristic polynomial of $C$ is $\lambda^3-\text{trace}(C)\lambda^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace of your matrix is $\|c\|^2_2 = c_1^2 +c_2^2 +c_3^2$ so your single non-zero eigenvalue should be equal to that and not just $c_1^2$.

I don’t recall if there is a theorem that proves this, but a **well-known (accepted) fact** for Hermitian matrices (i.e., those that can be diagonalized) dictates that the trace (the sum of the entries along the main diagonal) equals the sum of eigenvalues. Then, if your matrix has rank 1 and a single non-zero eigenvalue, then it must equal the trace. But whatever the case may be, it can be shown that the non-zero eigenvalue of your (very particular) matrix equals $\|c\|^2_2$ via direct computation.

Let $$c =\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix},$$ then your matrix is $c c^{\rm T}$. Then just multiply by $c$ to obtain $\|c\|^2_2 c$.

**Addendum:** Given $c$, three given eigenvectors of $cc^{\rm T}$ are $$\begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -c_2^2c_1 \\ c_1^2c_2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} -c_3^2c_1 \\ -c_3^2c_2 \\ (c_1^2+c_2^2)c_3 \end{bmatrix}$$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\|c\|^2_2$, 0 and 0.